# nircmd set microphone doesn't work

Tags: audio, windows-10, microphone

I'm trying to set my microphone volume with nircmd but it only sets the master volume.  I've tried

```
setsysvolume 6899 microphone
```

and it sets the master volume not the microphone.  I've also tried master, waveout, synth, cd, microphone, phone, aux, line, headphones and wavein.

Comment: Have a look at `nircmd.exe showsounddevices` and [this link](https://helping-squad.com/nircmd-change-windows-audio-settings-per-shortcut-or-hotkey/)